# All libGDX input statements are returning TRUE at once

Tags: java, libgdx, input

I'm fooling around with Box2D and libGDX and running into a peculiar problem with polling for input. Here's the code for the `Screen`'s `render()` loop:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, .2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Keys.LEFT)){
        Gdx.app.log("Input", "Left is being pressed.");
        pushyThingyBody.applyForceToCenter(-10f, 0);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Keys.RIGHT)){
        Gdx.app.log("Input", "Right is being pressed.");
        pushyThingyBody.applyForceToCenter(10f, 0);
    }
    world.step((1f/45f), 6, 2);
}
```

And the constructor is largely just setting up the `World`, `Box2DDebugRenderer`, and all the `Bodies` in the world:

```
public SandBox(PhysicsSandboxGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(800, 480);
    camera.setToOrtho(false);

    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.8f), true);
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(100, 300);

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
    circle.setRadius(6f);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = circle;
    fixtureDef.density = .5f;
    fixtureDef.friction = .4f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = .6f;

    fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    circle.dispose();

    BodyDef groundBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    groundBodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(0, 10));
    groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef);
    PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();
    groundBox.setAsBox(camera.viewportWidth, 10f);
    groundBody.createFixture(groundBox, 0f);
    groundBox.dispose();

    BodyDef pushyThingyBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    pushyThingyBodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    pushyThingyBodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(400, 30));
    pushyThingyBody = world.createBody(pushyThingyBodyDef);
    PolygonShape pushyThingyShape = new PolygonShape();
    pushyThingyShape.setAsBox(40f, 10f);
    FixtureDef pushyThingyFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    pushyThingyFixtureDef.shape = pushyThingyShape;
    pushyThingyFixtureDef.density = .4f;
    pushyThingyFixtureDef.friction = .1f;
    pushyThingyFixtureDef.restitution = .5f;
    pushyFixture = pushyThingyBody.createFixture(pushyThingyFixtureDef);
    pushyThingyShape.dispose();
}
```

Testing this on the desktop. Basically, whenever I hit the appropriate keys, neither of the `if` statements in the loop return true. However, when I click in the window, both statements return true, resulting in a 0 net force on the body. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're mixing up the keyboard and mouse a little bit. Your line:
`if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {`

should either be:

`if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {` ([Keys Javadoc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.Keys.html) if you're wanting keyboard input)

or

`if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT)) {` ([Buttons Javadoc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.Buttons.html) if you want mouse input)

I'm not sure if you've got any other problems just by looking at your code.